# Como ordenar números de um array?

Tags: php, array

Não acho a função para ordenar, de forma crescente, os números sorteados.

```
<?php
   $resultado = array();
   for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++){
        array_push($resultado,rand(1,60));
   }

   print_r($resultado); # Exibe os números sorteados fora de ordem.
   # print_r(sort($resultado)) # Exibe apenas o número 1
```

Comment: Perfeito!!! Algo tão simples e eu não usei a ordem correta.

Muito obrigado.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: Só complementando... Além do `sort`, existem muitas outras opções, cada uma específica para um caso. Documentações: [Ordenando Arrays](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/array.sorting.php)

Answer (score 6):

Você sabe como fazer, apenas não sabe como ver o resultado. A função `sort()` realiza o que você deseja em cima do próprio *array* que você passa. Então basta você imprimir o *array* de novo  após passar pela função que tudo vai dar certo. Você só não pode mandar imprimir o retorno da função porque segundo a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) (tem que ler ela para aprender, alias tem que ler tudo para programar, para usar sites novos, etc., ler é o segredo para evoluir), ela retorna um booliano se deu certo ou falhou. Ela não retorna outro *array* ordenado.

```
<?php
$resultado = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) array_push($resultado, rand(1, 60));
print_r($resultado);
sort($resultado);
print_r($resultado);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/4fab5P). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/blkmzvnx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/Sort.php).

Comment: Excelente observação! Obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

A [função `sort($resultado)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) não retorna a array ordenada mas sim um booleano caso corra sem erros, ou com erros..

A maneira correta de usar é:

```
sort($resultado);
```

e depois, `print_r($resultado)`.

Ou seja:

```
$resultado = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++){
    array_push($resultado, rand(1,60));
}

sort($resultado);
print_r($resultado);
```

exemplo: https://ideone.com/lcYGO9

Comment: Perfeito!! Obrigado pela excelente orientação.